# Как правильно выводить несколько компонентов React.js в одной функции

Tags: javascript, reactjs, семантика

Пробую сверстать тривиальный проект на React.js, покрутить и потыкать что да как для опыта. Столкнулся с такой проблемой: как я понял, по итогу всё сводится к тому, что функция App() в файле app.js должна возвращать один единственный блочный элемент (компонент)

```
function App() {
  return (
    <Some_main_component/>
  );
}
```

Но у меня уже структура такая что я тремя отдельными компонентами сверстал `<Header />`, `<Main />` и `<Footer />` и я по неопытности пытался вернуть в App(), что, разумеется, не работает

```
import Header from '...'
import Main from '...'
import Footer from '...'

function App() {
    return (
        <Header />
        <Main />
        <Footer />
    );
}
```

Решение проблемы которое приходит в голову - это сверстать условный `<Site />` компонент, импортировать в него 3 компонента выше и уже его выводить его в функцию App(). Просто оборачивать `<Header />`, `<Main />` и `<Footer />` в `<div>` на выходе, считаю вообще неуклюжим решением, ибо семантика покинет чат. Так что хочу узнать у опытных:

1. Считается ли грамотным 1-ый подход?
2. Как делают на реальных проектах?

Хочу научиться сразу правильно работать с данным инструментом, и что-то мне подсказывает, что это скорее костыли, нежели решения.

Всем заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Используйте [React.Fragment](https://react.dev/reference/react/Fragment), сокращенно `<>`

```
function App() {
    return (
        <>
            <Header />
            <Main />
            <Footer />
        </>
    );
}
```

Comment: подскажите, на коммерческих проектах так же используют React.Fragment, или же это скорее костыль, чем нормальная практика?

Comment: @Александр Это нормальная практика, там где надо, выводить несколько компонентов в одном блоке, не оборачивая их в отдельный узел DOM.

Comment: благодарю за информацию!